# KDE's maximise button does not fully maximise (dual monitor caused issue)

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, kde

I'm using Debian Stable 9.4 with the default KDE installation and working with two monitors.

On one of them, the maximise button does not fully maximise the window. Instead it has some sort of fixed vertical size which can't be extended.

I have uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Scq4OOS8oSw&feature=youtu.be) demonstrating the issue.

Does anyone know how to reset/fix this?